# Website with a database questions

Tags: python, asp.net, angularjs, database, web-applications

i'm creating a website connected to a database that pulls information for a team. It should be able to hold and process information without pushing it back into the database.
How do I approach this? What is a good technology to use for this. I know some sort of SQL will be needed for the database. What sort of technology should I use for developing this? I've heard of ASP.NET, AngularJS. What language what should I use with what technology? Also, are there any references or tutorials I could look at that could really help me get this job done? I was hoping to get this done in under a week!
Any help will be very appreciated. 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This question is so general. I hardly hold my emotions into play here. You want to create a web site in under a week without any experience what so ever (that's what I understand from your question, otherwise you won't ask for what technology to use). You can achieve this with any of the mentioned technologies, but you got to have a little bit of knowledge here. In my opinion you have to learn the basics of the field you are targeting and then go for that kind of challenges.

Comment: so i have background experience in coding in Python. Worked in C. C++. Embedded systems using C, C++. VHDL. even Assembler. Java obviously. I'm just asking for a friend who hasn't done too much, so I'm curious as to what you guys think would be a great place to start for him before I jump in and help him later on.

Comment: but I guess you guys are too focused on bashing people who actually want to...learn? You could've given suggestions on how to better describe the question. Suggestions on technologies and your own experience. Really anything...? lol

Comment: Ok, I understand. But you ask for something that people go to universities and dedicate years from their live to achieve. You want to do something in under a week which will be hard (to be done right) even for guys with a lot more experience than you in web development. With this question you are disrespectful for all the people who are inputting a lot of time into developing into this area. And to answer your question - Java/Spring and AngularJs are decent technologies for the job (those are the technologies that I used), and may others.

Comment: i get where you're coming from but it's practically pointless for you to answer if you didn't want to help. see saying AngularJS and/or JAVA/spring. that helps. that gives me a place to start researching and gives people an idea of what to look into. now it is my fault in not being more specific in my question, cause this will be a VERY basic webpage. this isnt at all flashy and wont have many capabilities. I'm just looking for a nice easy way to teach my friend or a starting point. Figured i'd ask people with more experience to help me find a good place for him to start.

Comment: Make a flow chart of your site, then post the flow chart of the project as a gig at upwork or freelancer.  You could be live in a week.